# Выбор наиболее подходящей строки в sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Сделал уникальный индекс и хочу по нему выбрать наиболее подходящую строчку.

```
create unique index table_uindex
    on table (ip, identity);
```

Выбираю

```
select * from table where 
          (identity = $2 and ip = $1::inet) or 
          (identity  IS NULL  and ip = $1::inet) or 
          (identity = $2 and ip IS NULL)
```

Как добиться чтоб строки выводились в этом порядке?
Помогите составить правильное выражение сортировки

Comment: *Как добиться чтоб строки выпадали* Строки не выпадают - чай, не лототрон. Строки выбираются и/или возвращаются. Все, для которых выражение отбора истинно, если не указано ограничение по количеству возвращаемых записей (LIMIT). Кстати, наличие или отсутствие индекса на результат не влияет - только на то, сколько времени будет потрачено на выборку. *в этом порядке?* Составить правильное выражение сортировки.

Comment: @Akina у индекса может быть встроенная сортировка

Comment: Ваша фраза в принципе не имеет смысла.

Comment: но сортировка в индексе есть) В Вашем комменте смысла 20%, но уже разобрался.

Comment: Наверное, Вам всё же стОит почитать ещё разок, что такое индекс... *но сортировка в индексе есть* В индексе есть значения указанного выражения для всех записей таблицы (или некоторых, если синтаксис допускает), хранящихся отсортированными в указанном порядке, плюс (если индекс некластерный) ссылка на саму запись в таблице (значение первичного индекса либо внутренний номер записи).

Answer (score 1):

Добавил индекс

create UNIQUE INDEX nas_idip_uindex  on networkaccess.nas (ip DESC NULLS LAST, identity DESC NULLS LAST);

И сортировку в запрос

```
select * from table where
          (identity = $2 and ip = $1::inet) or
          (identity IS NULL and ip = $1::inet) or
          (identity = $2 and ip IS NULL) ORDER BY ip DESC NULLS LAST, identity DESC NULLS LAST
```

Выдает в нужном порядке

Comment: Удалите индекс, и попробуйте обнаружить изменение результата...

Comment: да я знаю что дело не в индексе, просто индекс оптимальный для этого запроса.

Comment: *индекс оптимальный для этого запроса* Который в тексте вопроса - да, если добавить DESC NULLS LAST, в тексте ответа - нет, ибо выражение индекса (порядок следования полей в нём) не соответствует выражению сортировки.

Comment: я искал конструкцию NULLS LAST своим вопросом

Comment: переставить поля в индексе местами? ок, спс